# Kusto remove bracket from JSON array to a list

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, sentinel

I have a very simple question, however I can't seemed to find the answer to this.
How do I transform a json array variable

```
["one","two","three"]
```

into the following format suitable for string search using parameter ?

```
"one","two","three"
```

Thank you brain trusts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following functions:

- substring() - starting from index 1 and with length strlen()-2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strlenfunction
- strcat_array(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-arrayfunction

for example:

```
print input = dynamic(["one","two","three"])
| project output1 = substring(input, 1, strlen(input)-2),
          output2 = strcat('"', strcat_array(input, '","'), '"')
```

| output1 | output2 |
| --- | --- |
| "one","two","three" | "one","two","three" |